# error running virtualbox 4.1 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

i've installed ubuntu 14.04 today.
i had virtualbox 4.1 running perfectly on ubuntu 12.04.
Now, when i try starting Virtualbox 4.1 on ubuntu 14.04, i see this error:

```
Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver (vboxdrv) is either not loaded or there is a permission problem with /dev/vboxdrv. Please reinstall the kernel module by executing

'/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup'

as root. If it is available in your distribution, you should install the DKMS package first.
```

This package keeps track of Linux kernel changes and recompiles the vboxdrv kernel module if necessary.

what can i do? i saw another post but it's difficult to have clear answers..

i attached the message from Virtualbox when i try to run it:
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8581114/

others report messages here :

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8581147  (report from command line "/etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup")
pastebin.ubuntu.com/8581167 (report from command line "sudo lsmod")
excuse me because i can't post more than two links in the same question for reputation issues.. add http:// to the second link.. ;)

Comment: Welcome to AU! Can you try running `sudo service vboxdrv start`, `lsmod`, and `dkms status` please and [edit] your question to include their output?

Comment: first "sudo service vboxdrv start": * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                           
 * modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why

Comment: second , "sudo lsmod"..too long to paste here...

Comment: third, "sudo dkms status":
nvidia-173, 173.14.39, 3.13.0-38-generic, i686: installed
nvidia-173, 173.14.39, 3.2.0-70-generic-pae, i686: installed
vboxhost, 4.1.8: added

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include additional information (like the output of multi-lined diagnostic commands) and I encourage you to do it.

Comment: sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                    [ OK ] 
 * Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules                       [ OK ] 
 * Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS                  Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.13.0-38-generic (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.8/build/make.log for more information.

 * Failed, trying without DKMS
 * Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules                                      
 * Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong

Comment: As the error message states, there should be more info in `/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.8/build/make.log`. Can you please upload it (e. g. to a paste service) and include a link to it in your question? I would also like to see the output of `LC_MESSAGES=C dpkg -l linux-headers-3.13.0-37\*`.

Comment: sorry..which is the multi-lined diagnostic commands?

Comment: LC_MESSAGES=C dpkg -l linux-headers-3.13.0-37\*
dpkg-query: no packages found matching linux-headers-3.13.0-37*  ................AND i don t have permission to look at /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.8/build/make.log

Comment: Eh, I meant to say “multi-lined output of diagnostic commands” in reference to you comments cluttered up by hardly readable diagnostic messages.

Comment: To copy (and later upload) files owned by root copy them as super user: `sudo cat [SOURCE] > [DESTINATION]`. Example: `sudo cat /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.8/build/make.log > ~/vboxhost-4.1.8.make.log` places a copy of the content of `/var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.8/build/make.log` in a file named `vboxhost-4.1.8.make.log` in your home directory.

Comment: Again, please [edit] your question to include a link to the content of that file, so others can (at a later time) more easily follow and understand your problem, if they have a similar one.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is missing the kernel header files necessary to compile and install the Virtual Box driver kernel module. You can install the headers and rebuild the module with:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

The reason it was working before the upgrade was, that you apparently had installed the headers for the old kernel at some point and built the kernel module with their help as we can see in the output of `dkms status`.

Comment: sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                    [ OK ] 
 * Uninstalling old VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules                       [ OK ] 
 * Trying to register the VirtualBox kernel modules using DKMS                  Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.13.0-38-generic (i686)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/vboxhost/4.1.8/build/make.log for more information.

 * Failed, trying without DKMS
 * Recompiling VirtualBox kernel modules                               
 * Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong

Comment: I don't want to read that mess of co-joined output lines. Please put it some place that keeps the line breaks like [a paste service](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) or [your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/538259/edit).

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8581147/

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8581167/         (sudo lsmod)

Comment: Thanks. Can you add those links with descriptions to your question please, as they don't really belong to my answer? You can click the [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/538259/edit) link below your question to modify it.